# Trying to get an app permission for User creation of Graph api in azure active directory ,but failed in getting permissions

Tags: azure

I was trying to get app permission for User creation of Graph api in azure portal while providing permission, I get this error : not granted for organization, I tried many times and getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did your global admin grant the permission for the permissions you want? You can find this button right above the table where you add all the permissions.

[image: Grant the permission]

Comment: @Sai Bhaskar, did this solve your problem or are you still having issues?